# Android verify IAP subscription server side with Ruby

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, in-app-purchase, google-play

I have been googling and searching and this is killing me.  I am just trying to setup our RoR server to be able to query the google play purchases API to validate if a subscription has been renewed and I cannot seem to find an actual solution.  I have been through all of the google documentation.  It appears I need a service account as described here

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

But then I found this python article on how they actually want us to use the web server application flow

http://milancermak.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/server-side-verification-of-google-play-subsc/

I don't really care at this point, I just need to get the server to successfully talk to the Google API to validate/renew subscriptions.  I have found 0 articles on how this flow works.  Has anyone gotten this working??

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who stumbled on this, this was the craziest thing I have ever had to deal with but I managed to figure it out and do it right.  I want to thank the following articles for helping me slowly but surely get to the bottom of this.  I will add the most frustriating part of this is the steps I am going to list below, I am not 100% convinced they are all necessary because the only error I ever got during this was "403 Insufficient Permissions" so all I can really do here is tell you EVERYTHING I did and hope it works for you.

This article got everything working but was using the web access approach and stating that the service account wouldn't work

http://milancermak.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/server-side-verification-of-google-play-subsc/

This was a great implementation on the above article for Ruby

https://gist.github.com/cornflakesuperstar/5632813

This was a great article on how to get the key so that you could store it as an environment variable for Heroku

http://ar.zu.my/how-to-store-private-key-files-in-heroku/

This was a good article on how to setup the service account (note I am not the account owner of our services so I was flying blind on telling him how to do this.  This article worked)

https://developers.google.com/console/help/#activatingapis

This was the article on how you need to authorize the auto generated email from above

[How can I authorize with OAuth 2.0 for google's predictive API in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391685/how-can-i-authorize-with-oauth-2-0-for-googles-predictive-api-in-ruby)

The official Google Implementation for the API is here

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get

After countless late nights since I posted this article I was able to get this working WITH A SERVICE ACCOUNT with the following steps

1. I had our developer console admin generate me the service account information as described in the above developer article
2. I had our admin add the email account and allow it permission as described in the above stack overflow article
3. I followed the article on how to make the key a string that could be stored as a string

After tons of trial and error, miraculously got a "200" out of the API.  Here is my code

```
ISSUER = '45366745684568-afdasfasdfasdfasdfasdf@developer.gserviceaccount.com'  # From service account
APP_NAME = '<appname>'  # This value didn't seem to matter.  I think it is for logging
APP_VERSION = '1.0'     # This value didn't seem to matter.  I think it is for logging

  class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.google_api_client
    @@google_client ||= Google::APIClient.new(
      application_name:    APP_NAME,
      application_version: APP_VERSION
    ).tap do |client|

      # Load the key downloaded from the Google Developer Console
      if ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY'].nil?
        puts "Be sure that you have ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY'] defined in your environment."
        return
      end
      key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY'], 'notasecret'

      # Initialize the connection
      client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
        :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher',
        :issuer => ISSUER,
        :signing_key => key)
      client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
    end
  end

  def self.test_server(package_name, subscription_id, token)
    # Get the client
    client = self.google_api_client

    # Discover the subscriptions API
    publisher = client.discovered_api('androidpublisher', 'v2')

    # Make the API call
    result = client.execute(
      :api_method => publisher.purchases.subscriptions.get,
      :parameters => {'packageName' => package_name, 'subscriptionId' => subscription_id, 'token' => token}
    )
  end
end
```

Once I did all of the steps above I was still struggling (same 403 error).  I realized the thing that was burning me was the 'scope' was not properly set to 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'.  I hope this really helps someone.  This was tearing me apart and now it works perfect.

Thanks all of the mentioned articles for your help.

Comment: By the way, here's the updated gist url for the cornflakesuperstar link (the github account was renamed): https://gist.github.com/jkotchoff/5632813

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rails gist that verifies whether a Google Play subscription is currently active using the latest google-api-client gem:
https://gist.github.com/jkotchoff/e60fdf048ec443272045

That gist also includes documentation about how to create an OAuth token for which can be used offline.

ie.

> 1. visit http://console.developers.google.com
> 2. API Manager
> 3. Credentials
> 4. Create Credentials (OAuth client ID)
> 5. Application type: Web Application
> 6. Authorised redirect URIs: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
>
>    - the resultant client ID / client secret is for your access token
> 7. visit: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
> 8. Click the settings icon to show the OAuth 2.0 configuration
> 9. Tick 'Use your own OAuth credentials'
> 10. Enter the OAuth Client ID and OAuth Client secret that you have just created
> 11. Check the entry for 'Calendar API v3' in the scopes field and click 'Authorize APIs'
> 12. Click 'Allow'
> 13. Click 'Exchange authorization code for tokens'
>
>     - now you have a Refresh token and Access token for your client id / secret

Note, this gist has recently been upgraded to use version 0.9.x of the **google-api-client** gem. For an implementation that uses the deprecated v0.8.x of that gem, refer:
https://gist.github.com/jkotchoff/e60fdf048ec443272045/e3e2c867633900d9d6f53de2de13aa0a0a16bb03

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I was looking at this one too but I was having trouble getting the access token flow to work.  My solution was loosely based on this one but I actually got the service account flow to work (which is what I wanted for a Ruby server)